# Wix contact form submission and Google Analytics goal

Tags: google-analytics, velo

Could you help me understand how to catch a form submission event with Google Analytics if my site is built with Wix. Google Analytics is installed via **Google Tag Manager**.

Wix's documentation: https://support.wix.com/en/article/tracking-wix-contact-form-submissions-with-google-analytics

In Google Analytics the goal is organized as follows:
1. Goal type is "Event".
2. Category: "Leads".
3. Action: "Submitted".
4. Label: "New Lead"

At my site I fire in Chrome in console I can organize like this:

```
tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
tracker.send("event", "Leads", "Submitted", "New Lead");
```

And:
1. In Googlel Analytics I can catch the event in Real-Time section/Conversions.
2. In my Chrome browser I have installed GA debug plugin. It is reacting to the event:

```
eventAction      (&ea)   Submitted
analytics_debug.js:23 eventCategory    (&ec)   Leads
analytics_debug.js:23 eventLabel       (&el)   New Lead
analytics_debug.js:23 hitType          (&t)    event
```

But when I just submit the form at my site, nothing happens: neither Real-Time report catches the conversion, nor GA debug plugin shows any activity.

Could you help me adjust the system so that Google Analytics should catch the form submission event.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if you've figured this out as of yet. If you have, great!

It sounds like you're trying to set this up through the coding on the site itself. Instead, I recommend setting up the event via Google Tag Manager to fire on a click of the form's submit button. It's an easier way to get events to fire if you're having trouble getting the code to function.

[Wix has a great tutorial on how to do this posted here.](https://support.wix.com/en/article/tracking-click-events-with-google-tag-manager)

Comment: Please answer the question and leave links for the comments.

Comment: This won't work if you have some form of validation on your form. In other words, your suggestion will track the clicks on the submission button, and some of them may not be actual submissions if the validation has failed.